# How to request a APK file from MVC route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-mvc-routing, static-files

How do I request a Static file (.apk) from MVC route?

I tried the following, But of no use:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.apk");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" in your web.config , in that case you must write custom HttpHandler for .apk extension urls , but if you turn above value to true then this must be working fine.Thanks